# How to append -webkit-filter properties by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote the following codes in order to make element which has id=sample grayscale(0.6) and blur(5px). But it turns out that the latter -webkit-filter property substitutes for the previous one instead of appending to it. I can only add one -webkit-filter property every time. Is it possible to append the blur to grayscale? Just make clear that I am using latest chrome, so -webkit-filter works on my navigator.

```
$('#grayscale').click(function() {
    $('#sample').css({"-webkit-filter" : "grayscale(0.6)"})
});
$('#blur').click(function() {
    $('#sample').css({"-webkit-filter" : "blur(5px)"})
});
```

Comment: `$('#grayscale').onclick` does this even work? jQuery doesn't have `onclick` method, do you mean `.click()` or `.on('click')`?

Comment: Do you also need a trigger for removing those applied styles?

Comment: @undefined Thank you for correcting this. It was a typo. I mean .click().

Answer (score 0):

You can just add to (or remove from) the existing filter.

```
$('#grayscale').on('click', function() {
    var $sample = $('#sample');
    var new_filter = "grayscale(0.6)"; 
    var old_filter = $sample.css("-webkit-filter");
    if(old_filter.indexOf(new_filter) == -1){
        $sample.css("-webkit-filter", old_filter + ' ' + new_filter);
    }
    else {
        $sample.css("-webkit-filter", old_filter.replace(new_filter, ''));
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zzmJR/

Answer (score 0):

some versions of jquery fail at adding browser specific styles

and sometimes it may be faster with JavaScript

var sample = $('#sample');
sample.style.webkitFilter = "grayscale(0.6)";

Answer (score 0):

I guess your best option is to use a common controller. This way you can apply different values for grayscale and blur. Ideally you should do it with an input instead of just a click on an element. Something like this:

```
var gValue = 0;
var bValue = 0;
$('#grayscale').click(function() {
    gValue= 0.6;
    change();
});
$('#blur').click(function() {
    bValue = 0.5;
    change();
});

function change(){
   var filter = "grayscale(" + gValue + ") blur(" + bValue + ")";
   $('#sample').css("webkitFilter", filter});
}
```